# Передача итоговой стоимости в платежный шлюз

Tags: javascript, php, curl

Имеется кривенький самописный магазин. В магазине реализована корзина, вот кусок кода на JS, который отвечает за отображение товара, стоимости позиции, количества, кнопок "добавить", "удалить", и главное -- итоговой стоимости:

```js
function showCart() {
  $.getJSON('catalog/wine-sets.json', function (data) {
    //вывод корзины
    if (!isEmtpy(cart)) {
      $('.main-cart').html('the cart is empty');
    }
    else {
          var goods = data;
          var out = '';
          var unitsprice = 0;
          ttlbttl = 0;
          var delcost = 0;
          for (var id in cart) {
            ttlbttl += goods[id].bottles * cart[id];
          }
          for (var id in cart) {
            //out = Object.keys(cart).reduce((total, id) => total += cart[id], 0);
          }
          for (var id in cart) {
            unitsprice += goods[id].price * cart[id];
          }
          for (var id in cart) {
              //var bttlsumm = goods[id].bottles*cart[id];
              out += `<div class="main-cart-unit"><img src="${goods[id].image}">`;
              out += `<div class="main-cart-description-block"><div class="cart-goods-name"> ${goods[id].name  } </div>`;
              out += `<div class="cart-goods-description"> ${goods[id].country  }`;
              out += ` ${goods[id].region  },`;
              out += ` ${goods[id].producer  } </div>`;
              out += `<div class="cart-goods-subdesription"> ${goods[id].year }`;
              out += ` ${goods[id].sweetness },`;
              out += ` ${goods[id].color },`;
              out += ` ${goods[id].sparkling } </div>`;
              out += `<div class="main-cart-description-buttons-block"><button data-id="${id}" class="delete-position-cart">-</button>`;
              out += `<div class="id-counting-cart"> ${cart[id]  } </div>`;
              out += `<button data-id="${id}" class="add-position-cart">+</button> </div>  </div>`;
              out +=  `<div class="cart-goods-price"> ${(cart[id]*goods[id].price).toFixed(2)}€ </div> </div>`;
              out += '<br>';
    }
    $('.main-cart').html(out);
    if (ttlbttl >= 36) {
      delcost = 0;
    }
    else {
      delcost = ttlbttl;
    }
    $('.delcost').html(`Delivery cost: <div class="subdelcost">${(delcost).toFixed(2)}€</div>`);
    $('.unitsprice').html(`TOTAL: <div class="subunitsprice">${(unitsprice + delcost).toFixed(2)}€</div>`);
    $('.delete-position-cart').on('click', delGoods);
    $('.add-position-cart').on('click', addlGoods);
    console.log(unitsprice, ttlbttl);
    $('#cheched').on('change', function () {
        if ( $('#cheched').prop('checked') && ttlbttl >=6 )  {
            $('.cart-submit-button').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('.cart-submit-button').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
  }
  });
}
```

Для приема платежей в магазине был найден платежный шлюз от Paydoo. В документации требуется создать post-запрос, откуда будет выдергиваться идентификатор платежа и т.д., вот его код:

```php
function request() {
    $url = "https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts";
    $data = "entityId=8a8294185e5c61f5015e61d25f250dca" .
                "&amount=92.00" .
                "&currency=EUR" .
                "&paymentType=DB";
 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                   'Authorization:Bearer OG***gzOQ=='));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// this should be set to true in production
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $responseData = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $responseData;
}
$responseData = request();
```

Затем скриптом вызывается виджет для ввода данных карты, вот его код:

```html
<form class="paymentWidgets" action="{success_url.php}" data-brands="MASTER VISA">
      <script src="https://test.oppwa.com/v1/paymentWidgets.js?checkoutId={checkoutId}"></script>
    </form>
```

Каким образом можно итоговую стоимость из моей корзины передать в виджет от Paydoo?

Comment: в виджет сумму передавать не надо

Comment: а каким образом принимать оплату на ту сумму, что у меня в итоговой стоимости?

Comment: сумму надо передавать не в "виджет", а в "post-запрос". обычным способом: пользователь заполняет форму, отправляет её на сервер, сервер отправляет пост запрос в платежную систему и показывает клиенту виджет

Comment: а каким образом этом можно реализовать,  не подскажете? а то я совсем идиот...

Comment: Ну обратитесь к программисту, если так. Я не могу тут в комментариях полностью пересказать учебник по веб-программированию.